# My treemap breaks after sorting it because "comparator used for the treemap is inconsistent with equals"

Tags: java, sorting, dictionary

I needed to sort my treemap based on it's value. The requirements of what I'm doing are such that I have to use a sorted map. I tried the solution here: [Sort a Map<Key, Value> by values (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java/3420912#3420912) however as the comments say, this will make getting values from my map not work. So, instead I did the following:

```
class sorter implements Comparator<String> {
    Map<String, Integer> _referenceMap;
    public boolean sortDone = false;
    public sorter(Map<String, Integer> referenceMap) {
        _referenceMap = referenceMap;
    }
    public int compare(String a, String b) {
        return sortDone ? a.compareTo(b) : _referenceMap.get(a) >= _referenceMap.get(b) ? -1 : 1;
    }
}
```

So I leave sortDone to false until I'm finished sorting my map, and then I switch sortDone to true so that it compares things as normal. Problem is, I still cannot get items from my map. When I do myMap.get(/*anything*/) it is always null still.

I also do not understand what the comparator inconsistent with equals even means.

Comment: can you add the code where you are getting the null value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I also do not understand what the comparator inconsistent with equals even means.

As per the [contract of the Comparable interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).

> The natural ordering for a class C is said to be consistent with equals if and only if e1.compareTo(e2) == 0 has the same boolean value as e1.equals(e2) for every e1 and e2 of class C. Note that null is not an instance of any class, and e.compareTo(null) should throw a NullPointerException even though e.equals(null) returns false.
>
> It is strongly recommended (though not required) that natural orderings be consistent with equals.

I believe you need to change the line :

```
 _referenceMap.get(a) >= _referenceMap.get(b) ? -1 : 1;
```

to

```
 _referenceMap.get(a).compareTo(_referenceMap.get(b));
```

Since if the `Integer` returned by `_referenceMap.get(a)` is actually `==` in value to the `Integer` returned by `_referenceMap.get(b)` then you should ideally return `0`, not `-1`.

Comment: when I do "sortedData.firstKey()" it gives me the correct key, but still when I try "sortedData.get("smethingHere")" it is null every time.

Comment: @Macmee How are you putting values in `Map` ? Can you show us ?

Comment: I am putting them into my map using the put method, just iterating over a list of items (String, Integer), for example sortedData.put("Ardvark", 1000); sortedData.put("Zebra", 99999); and the map automatically sorts naturally by key so that it would have the order of Ardvark and then Zebra, however I want my treemap to sort by value so that I have Zebra and then Ardvark. The method I posted sorts my map fine, I can even print sortedData.toString() and see it sorted, but if I try sortedData.get("Zebra") then it returns null.

Answer (score 0):

It means you must implement, ie override, the `equals()` method to compare the same field(s) you are comparing for the `compareTo()` method.

It is good practice to override the `hashCode()` method to return a hash based on the same fields too.

Comment: but in my source, for what object do I override equals() for?